# CloudFront versioning and invalidation when you cannot change the link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront to embed some JavaScript on another persons website. The other person installs the JavaScript by placing the link on their website. They use the link rather than the JavaScript itself so that I can change the JavaScript to push updates to them without them touching it at all.

When I push these changes to CloudFront it takes a while for the changes to propagate which isn't desirable. What the best method for changing the file in this case?

Here are the methods I tried:

1. Let the changes propagate on their own. This is bad because it can theoretically take up to 24 hours.
2. Invalidate the cache using the API requests or the UI. This is okay, but it still takes 10-30 minutes.
3. Version the files (file_v1.js) and have the other person change the link manually.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no third option here. If changing the link is an option for you, and other person's site is NOT served through any CDN it is the fastest way.